# Error when trying to install rsync with Brew on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, homebrew

Im trying to install rsync on macOS high sierra using Brew :

```
brew install rsync
```

But i got this error :

```
Error: Could not create /usr/local/Cellar <br>
Check you have permission to write to /usr/local
```

Comment: Are you trying to  use sudo ??

Comment: yes, but i got this error when im trying with `sudo` : `Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all build scripts full access to your system.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just to uninstall and reinstall brew on your mac:
Before that execute to below command:

```
brew bundle dump
```

After that execute

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: This seems like killing a mosquito with a cannonball. Is there a less extreme solution available?